# How do I print out the values in a vector of unique pointer objects(Range based for loops)? C++

Tags: c++, for-loop, smart-pointers

I have a snippet of code here and I have a vector of smart pointers objects that are filled, how would I be able to print all the values of all the objects using **range based for loops?** I do not want the addresses, but the value. Thank you in advance.

```cpp
void printInfo(const std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Bird> >&fullData )
{
    for(auto &info : fullData)
    {
        std::cout<< &info <<endl; //I want this to print getName() for each object, but how do I do that with range-based-for-loop? Something like this.. info->getName()

    }
}
```

```or-tag-here
void fillFlock( std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Bird> > &cage)  
{

  size_t cageSize;
  std::string name;

  std::cout << "Bird cage size: " <<std::endl;
  std::cin >> cageSize;

  //set container size
  cage.resize(cageSize);

    for(auto &bird : cage)
    {
        std::cout<<"Bird Name " <<std::endl;
        std::cin >> name;

        bird.reset(new Bird(name));
    }
}
```

```or-tag-here
int main()  
{
    std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Bird> > m_flock;
    fillFlock(m_flock);
    printInfo(m_flock);
}
```

Comment: std::cout<< *info <<endl;

Comment: It doesn't work, it prompts an error saying Invalid operands binary expression

Comment: You have to write a `print()` function to your object `Bird`

Comment: Could you provide definition of Bird class then?

Comment: @RoiHatam it doesn't need a ``print`` function, but there does need to be an operator ``<<`` which takes type ``Bird``

Comment: @JamesElderfield Sure, function overloading is just another way to do it.

Comment: @RoiHatam A ``print`` function would certainly be sensible, but I was just making the point that the above code won't work as written if you just add a ``print`` function

Comment: @James Elderfield Other way is to define Bird conversion to ex.: const char*

Comment: It should also be `for (auto const &info : fullData)`

Comment: `void fillFlock(std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Bird>>& cage)
{
    size_t cageSize;
    std::string name;
    
    std::cout << "Bird cage size: " <<std::endl;
    std::cin >> cageSize;
    
    //set container size
    cage.resize(cageSize);
    
    for(auto &bird : cage)
    {
        std::cout<<"Bird Name " <<std::endl;
        std::cin >> name;
    
        bird.reset(new Bird(name));
    }
}
`

Comment: `int main()
{
    std::vector< std::unique_ptr<Bird> > m_flock;
    fillFlock(m_flock);
    printInfo(m_flock);
}`

Comment: @Eusto please do not put code in comment, it's hard to read. If it's relevant, edit your question.

Comment: I've edited my question, please have a look at it. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

You're actually making a new pointer to your unique pointers, and then printing the address of that. Use `&` to make a pointer and `*` to dereference (get the value). In other words,

```
std::cout << *info << std::endl;
```

**EDIT: Question was changed and extra context added**

If you want to call the function on `info`, then call the function,

```
std::cout << info->getName() << std::endl;
```

The type of `info` is just `std::unique_ptr<Bird>&` if that is what is throwing you.

Perhaps you want this to happen automatically with the streaming operator. A way of doing this is to define a `operator<<` that takes your `Bird` class. You can do this by adding the following declaration to your `Bird` class,

```
class Bird {
    friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Bird& bird);
};
```

and then in your source file add the definition,

```
std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& out, const Bird& bird) {
    return out << bird.getName();
}
```

This assumes that your `getName` function is const-qualified, which it really should be.

Comment: I have edited my question to make it clearer, please have a look at it. Thank you in advance.

Comment: As a very minor point, you don't really need to define the operator as a friend, assuming `getName` is public.